# Using lua_call a lot of times in c++ function

Tags: c++, lua

first of all I'm sorry for my english.

My question is about how to use lua_call more than one time in C++ function. I have a program that uses lua as primary language, but it accept c++ plugins to add functionalities. I want to call a LUA function from c++, and call that c++ function in LUA Runtime.
I want to write a c++ function with a progress while is working, then pass this progress to a LUA function which is responsible to show that progress to user.

For now I've a test function in LUA:

```
function ShowText(text)
    Dialog.Message("Hi", text);
    return true;
end
```

and a c++ function:

```
static int Test(lua_State *L){
    lua_pushstring(L, "Hi There");
    lua_call(L, 1, 1);

    lua_pushstring(L, "Again");
    lua_call(L, 1, 1); 

    return 0;
}
```

Then i call this function from LUA using:

```
Test.Test(ShowText);
```

All works fine with the first **lua_call** but then the LUA pile is cleared, function dissapear and the second **lua_call** try to use the return boolean of first call instead  function.

i want something like this:

```
static int Test(lua_State *L){
    int total = 10;

    for (int j; j<total; j++){
        lua_pushnumber(L, j);
        lua_pushnumber(L, j);
        lua_call(L, 2, 1);
        bool continue = IRLUA_PLUGIN_CheckBoolean(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1); //Delete the last boolean

        if (continue == false){
            break;
        }
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

and in LUA:

```
function ShowProgress(actual, final)
    local percent = (actual/final)*100;

    Dialog.Message("Working", "I'm in "..actual.." from "..final.." ("..percent.."%)");

    return true;
end
```

NOTES:

**Dialog.Message** is a function of the program tha i'm using to show a message. Is like **MessageBox(NULL, Text, Title, MB_OK);** in c++.

**IRLUA_PLUGIN_CheckBoolean** is a function of plugin SDK that check if argument is booleand and return its value, or return an error if not.

I can do it with **lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX , "FunctionName");**, but is not what i want.

Someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have understood the problem well. Here is how you fix it.

In your first example, `lua_call` pops the function from the stack so you need to duplicate it first. Also, the boolean returned by the function is useless, so you need to pop it or just not ask it to lua_call by setting the last argument to 0:

```
static int Test(lua_State *L) {

    lua_pushvalue(L, 1); /* duplicate function */

    lua_pushstring(L, "Hi There");
    lua_call(L, 1, 0);

    lua_pushstring(L, "Again");
    lua_call(L, 1, 0); 

    return 0;
}
```

Now applying that to your second example:

```
static int Test(lua_State *L) {
    int total = 10;

    for (int j = 0; j<total; j++) {
        lua_pushvalue(L, 1); /* duplicate function */
        lua_pushnumber(L, j);
        lua_pushnumber(L, total);
        lua_call(L, 2, 1);
        bool keep_going = IRLUA_PLUGIN_CheckBoolean(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1); /* pop the boolean */

        if (keep_going == false) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(I have fixed a few other issues with your code: the second number passed should probably be `total`, not `j`, you don't want to use `continue` as a variable name...)

Comment: Thanks for all ;)

I'll do some tests but should work. You're right, I want to pass total instead j again, and continue as variable... too bad. Thanks again!!